# Spring form ID field not populated on POST

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

In the below Spring form, my object's ID field is populated, but when I receive the submission in the controller method, all of the form's fields are populated except for the ID field. I've quintuple-checked that the field type and getter/setter types are all the same non-primitive, as I've seen many of the other questions on SO similar to this and that seems to be the common issue. The controller doesn't have any method-level @ModelAttributes, so it isn't being populated otherwise.

Here's the declaration of the POST method, as I debugged it on the first containing line and found that the form's id field is empty:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{orgId}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String editOrganizationPost(@PathVariable int orgId,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute(ORG_FORM) OrganizationForm orgForm,
        BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes att,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Here's the form object:

```
public class OrganizationForm {

private Integer id;
@NotBlank
private String name;
@NotBlank
private String description;
private Set<User> users;

int moveToOrganizationId = 0;
String moveToOrganizationName;
int[] moveFromOrganizationUserSelect = null; // List of selected users
                                                // to be moved to a new
                                                // organization

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public int getMoveToOrganizationId() {
    return this.moveToOrganizationId;
}

public void setMoveToOrganizationId(int moveToOrganizationId) {
    this.moveToOrganizationId = moveToOrganizationId;
}

public String getMoveToOrganizationName() {
    return this.moveToOrganizationName;
}

public void setMoveToOrganizationName(String moveToOrganizationName) {
    this.moveToOrganizationName = moveToOrganizationName;
}

public int[] getMoveFromOrganizationUserSelect() {
    return this.moveFromOrganizationUserSelect;
}

public void setMoveFromOrganizationUserSelect(
        int[] moveFromOrganizationUserSelect) {
    this.moveFromOrganizationUserSelect = moveFromOrganizationUserSelect;
}

public boolean isNew() {
    return this.id == null || this.id == 0;
}

}
```

Here is the markup from the JSP file:

```
<form:form method="post" action="${submitUrl}" commandName="organizationForm">
                <form:errors path="*" />
                <form:hidden path="id" />
                <table class="adminTable editContent">
                    <tr class="bg_lgtGrey">
                        <td><fmt:message
                                key="manageOrganizations.organizationForm.name" />:</td>
                        <td><form:input path="name" cssClass="inputbox"
                                tabindex="4" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg_lgtGrey">
                        <td><fmt:message
                                key="manageOrganizations.organizationForm.description" />:</td>
                        <td><form:textarea path="description"
                                cssClass="inputbox" tabindex="4" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right"><c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${!organizationForm.new}">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                        id="submit_button" value="Update" />
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                        id="submit_button" value="Create" />
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
```

And here is the generated HTML:

```
<form id="organizationForm" action="/admin/organizations/1" method="post">

                <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="1">
                <table class="adminTable editContent">
                    <tbody><tr class="bg_lgtGrey">
                        <td>Organization Name:</td>
                        <td><input id="name" name="name" class="inputbox" tabindex="4" type="text" value="Organization1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg_lgtGrey">
                        <td>Organization Description:</td>
                        <td><textarea id="description" name="description" class="inputbox" tabindex="4"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right">

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button" value="Update">


                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </form>
```

I used Chrome devtools to catch the POST data and here it is:

```
id=1&name=Organization1&description=
```

...yet at the breakpoint at the first line of the editOrganizationPost method, the form.id field is set to 0.

I have spent forever trying to figure out why it will bind the name and description but not the ID when sent. I could obviously just inject the ID from the path variable but I am dumbfounded as to why it wouldn't just populate the field naturally.

Comment: You don't need to use the non-primitive wrappers for Spring to work.  That just makes it so the values *could* be null.  Anyway, can you use your browsers debug tools (Chrome's Dev Tools, FireFox's FireBug, IEs Dev Tools) to check what your browser is posting?  I just want to make sure that it's actually posting the id field.  Also, would it be possible to see the .jsp form prior to rendering?  I particularly want to see how you are coding the inputs (JSTL spring tags, etc).

Comment: I've edited the post to include the JSP form and the POST data.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve the issue, but my experience with the framework taught me to always name the method parameter after the class e.g. `OrganizationForm organizationForm` instead of `OrganizationForm orgForm`.

Comment: The ORG_FORM constant I have as the value for the @ModelAttribute annotations = "organizationForm", same as the commandName attribute of the <form:form> tags. Shouldn't make a difference what the Java method variable is named.

Comment: Do you have any weird `@InitBinder`s setup?

Comment: Nope, and this class does not inherit or implement from any other class. I have a `@Controller` annotation and a class-level `@RequestMapping` set, that's it.

Comment: The strangest thing is that you say it's zero and not null.

Comment: I ended up changing the OrganizationForm.id field to "orgId", and then swapped the "orgId" path variable in the request mapping to "id" to avoid any possible conflict. This seems to work, so I'm led to believe Spring is possibly doing something with any field named "id" in its model attributes, but I haven't yet figured out what. Hopefully I can figure out why, or somebody can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. the id field would always be set to 0. Changing the id field to something else didn't work either. After more hit and trail, removing

`disabled="true"`

from

`<form:input path"id" disabled="true"/>`

fixed the issue. 
I assumed
`<form:hidden path="id">`
would give the same error but it didn't.